# AngularJs dropdown values clearing out model value

Tags: angularjs, html-select

My dropdown html looks like this:

```
<select name="originType" class="form-control"
        ng-model="myLocationType"
        ng-options="type.Key as type.Value for type in allLocationTypes"
        required></select>
```

This works fine to populate the dropdown.  However, when I'm loading the page and populating it with model data, the value that should be selected never is.  The dropdown is always on the default (blank) value.  I have no problem with dropdowns that are not key/value pairs.  For example:

```
<select name="shipId" class="form-control"
        ng-model="WageAgreement.ShipId"
        ng-options="shipId for shipId in manufacturers"
        required></select>
```

Comment: Angular always provides a provision for Default option in select. Which is shown when model is undefined. If you want default option to be something else then assign a value to the select model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populating the model value should work if the model value matches up with the supplied value in the array. See http://jsfiddle.net/5qp54/2/ where 2 is selected when set as the model value for WageAgreement.ShipId

```
var mod = angular.module("myApp", []);

mod.controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.allLocationTypes = [
        {Key: 1, Value: "Shipyard 1"},
        {Key: 2, Value: "Shipyard 2"},
        {Key: 3, Value: "Shipyard 3"}
    ];
    $scope.WageAgreement = {};

    //Populate value here
    $scope.WageAgreement.ShipId = 2;
});
```

Does your model value match the Key in your object array? I suspect something isn't matching up if it is not selecting the value on the dropdown.

If this doesn't answer your question, can you update your post with a jsfiddle or sample of how you populate manufacturers/allLocations and WageAgreement?

Comment: You were right.  The Key is a C# enum.  The model was being returned using  [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] which caused the enum to be returned as a string that read like the enum.  The dropdown was being populated by getting the enum directly which meant the value was stored as an integer.  Changed it to use the string value of the enum and everything works!